# How do I get 18.04 server LTS install to accept network settings and proceed?

Tags: server, 18.04, configuration, dhcp

During the fresh install of 18.04 server LTS (bare metal) the process craps out at network config.  Box being Dell PE2950, it has two Gb-NICS, and both NICS aappear functional, as do the network/DHCP/DNS, as I can PXE boot off of either and push various images to the box.  DNS diagnostics of both DNS servers show good, and the rest of the network resolves fine.  I believe I have tried every combination of disabled/dhcp, disabled/static, bond/dhcp, bond static, dhcp/disabled, static/disabled between the two nics, but the install halts at this step with time-out error.

I should note, perhaps, that I am installing from USB.

18.04.2 live server 64:  fails with network setup timeout

18.04.1 server 64:  works

Comment: Have you tried both server iso file types: [Ubuntu Server (old style)](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/bionic/ubuntu-18.04.1-server-amd64.iso) and [Ubuntu Live Server (new style)](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.2/ubuntu-18.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso)? If you want some other version, browse the [this](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/bionic/) and [this](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.2) directory.

Comment: Edit your question and include the output of `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `ifconfig`. Report back to @heynnema